# Case Statement with two DATEDIFF

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have this code:

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime                           
  , @EndDate datetime                       
                         
----First Day of Last Month
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(mm,-1,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,GETDATE()),0)) --First Day of Last Month

--First Day of Current Month
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0) 


SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), b.BookInDT, 101) AS [BookInDT], 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), o.AwareDT, 101) AS [DT ICE Hold],
    case when (dbo.fn_IsInJailByBookInID(b.BookInID)) = 1 then 'yes' else 'no' end as [InJail] , 
    traa.AgencyName AS [Agency Name], 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), r.ReleasedDT, 101) AS [ReleaseDT], 


    DATEDIFF (day, b.bookindt, @enddate) as [Total Days InJail], 

    DATEDIFF (day, @StartDate, @EndDate) AS [Days InJail for Month],

    case when (b.bookindt = @enddate) then DATEDIFF (day, @StartDate, @EndDate) ELSE DATEDIFF (day, b.bookindt, @enddate) end as [test1]

FROM ...
```

It seems like the first case statement condition is being ignored. The two stand alone `datediff()` functions calculate the correct days, A&B from the screenshot.

[image]

What I want to do is set the `test1` column so any `bookindt` before `02/01/2023` will be `28`, and after to use the datediff between `bookindt` and `@enddate`.

Comment: Be aware: SQL Server 2012 went formally end of life in July last year. That means it hasn't had any updates since that date... **not even critical security patches**. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I look at this:

```
--First Day of Current Month
SET @EndDate = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

And I expect `@EndDate` will be `2023-03-01` (March 1st).

Then I look at this expression:

```
when (b.bookindt = @enddate)
```

And compare it to the visible values for `bookindt`, and **NONE** of them match March 1st. Therefore the `case` expression is doing exactly what you told it to do.

Based on how you highlighted the data, I think you might want this:

```
when (b.bookindt < @startdate)
```

But you should take the time to work through the logic and understand why it's right or wrong before using it.

Comment: Thanks, Joel Coehoorn, the case statement works with the < @startdate change.